# <compatible-screens> to support phones between 4.5 inch to 6 inch

Tags: android, google-play, google-cardboard, android-screen-support, google-vr

I am creating a VR(Virtual Reality) video player for android. I want to restrict the app for devices with screen size between 4.5 inch to 6 inch because most of the VR headset support only phones within this range. I don't know what should I put inside my `<compatible-screens></compatible-screens>` for the same.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
    <supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="false"/>
```

Comment: I want my app to be compatible for those screens only in the app store. So should I add `<compatible-screens>` instead of `<supports-screens>`?

Comment: if you dont want allow other screened devices except large and normal to run your app, then use <compatible-screens>